# Transferring data from Action Class to Jsp

Tags: java, struts

I am new to Java and working on Struts i want to send the data from my action class to the jsp.

I am retreiving the employee details from database and want to display them in a grid view in the jsp so can you help me with it. As multiple records will be returned how to assign each record to the table row

Comment: Are you using form beans/dyna beans? Which struts version you are using? Without more details it is impossible to get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to put your employee record in a list like data structure and than on the jsp page you can iterate this with the help of `logic:iterate` tag. please see the documentation on how to use this tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Struts 1 and you are saving your list in request then code may look like this:

Action class execute method

```
List<String> names= new ArrayList<String>(); 
names.add("A");
names.add("B");
request.setAttribute("names", names);
```

In JSP

```
<logic:iterate name="names" id="namesId">

    <span>
        Names <bean:write name="namesId"/>
    </span>

</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you prefering the Struts2...

Create a Action class having:

```
public class Actionmain{
ActionForm aform=new ActionForm(); // which generate the setters
```

and getters:

```
public String getProdCode(ActionForm aform){
    if (reqLogPCForm ==null){
        return "Error";
    }else if{
        ActionVO AVO=null;
        try{
            VO = execute(hmInput);
        }
    }
```